# How to read .xls(ms excel) file in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

How to read .xls(ms excel) file in blackberry application.
Is there any api available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing in the public BlackBerry API to do this, but you could probably easily port an opensource API to do what you need.  A quick search with Google for "Java Excel API" brings bacK:

http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/

Comment: i think this api is for java not for j2me.any 3rd party api for j2me?

Answer (score 1):

The Java Excel API wont work because Blackberry api lacks java.io.File class,Instead try for CSV.
[how to create a Excel format file?](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/how-to-create-a-Excel-format-file/td-p/751071)